# JWT HttpOnly Cookie, who sets the Authorization header?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, oauth, jwt

so i am doing an OAuth between my FrontEnd (ReactJS) and my BackEnd (Spring Boot),

since i am setting a cookie httpOnly, my frontend cant access it obv.

but now, since the token needs to be send on every request to check if the user is Authorized or not, how we go about that?

If i send any request with axios for example, how do i get the Authorized Token in the header?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, you can't. If the cookie is httponly, there is no way to add its content to the `Authorization` header. You either need to store tokens directly in the JS code (e.g. in local storage or memory - taking into consideration the risk), or you need to add a proxy between the APIs and your SPA. The proxy will extract the token from the cookie and place it in the `Authorization` header.

Comment: What about handling the Auth only via. cookies?
Store the Auth and Refresh Tokens in httpOnly cookies, 
the frontend always sends them to the backend back, i can extract them and verify them,
would that be considered a good practise?

I mean that way i would work without the Auth Header

Comment: Yes, that is good practice. If you're in control of the APIs and they can read tokens from cookies, then you go this way.

Comment: Thank you alot for your help,

i might go the client -> middleware(server) -> server, way in the future, will see if it is necessary in my case,

thanks alot again to help me understand it a bit more :)